# How to send data to my server using android application.?

Tags: php, android

I know how to send it via `HttpClient` and `HttpPost` and then using `$_POST['xyz']` in PHP, but `HttpPost` and `HttpClient` are deprecated. I want to use HttpURLConnection.

I know I have to use `OutputStream` stream, and write the data to this stream, but what will be the code for PHP to receive the data?.
I don't need the whole code, just guide me with the PHP.

Comment: `$_POST` is not deprecated I think. You can still use that. How are you saying it's deprecated? because of frameworks? they still do the same thing behind the hood.

Comment: @Roljhon I think the OP referred to the client side implementations being deprecated. (hint: "they")

Comment: @arkascha `but what will be the code for php to receive the data? don't need the whole code,just guide me with the php`?

Comment: Yes, the OP expect that another strategy has to be used on the server side _if the client side uses another strategy because the previous options are deprecated._

Comment: @arkascha ahhh, little confused, but that can still help him understand that `$_POST` is not deprecated :D

Comment: If i use $_POST['xyz'] in php .then how to send the data using HttpURLConnection and how to use the label 'xyz' ?